# Erlang/OTP fails to compile on Solaris 11 11/11

Tags: gcc, erlang, solaris

After upgrading to Solaris 11 (11/11) from Solaris 11 Express I'm no longer able to compile Erlang/OTP (in order to build couchdb), same with a fresh install of Solaris 11 64-bit in VirtualBox.

After `./configure`, `gmake` fails with some assembler issue. I tried Erlang OTP R14B03, R14B04 and R15B without success.

> gcc -g -O2 -I/home/admin/Workarea/otp_src_R14B03/erts/i386-pc-solaris2.11  -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -fno-tree-copyrename  -DERTS_SMP -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wdeclaration-after-statement -DUSE_THREADS -D_THREAD_SAFE -D_REENTRANT -DPOSIX_THREADS -D_POSIX_PTHREAD_SEMANTICS  -Ii386-pc-solaris2.11/opt/smp -Ibeam -Isys/unix -Isys/common -Ii386-pc-solaris2.11 -Izlib  -Ipcre -Ihipe -I../include -I../include/i386-pc-solaris2.11 -I../include/internal -I../include/internal/i386-pc-solaris2.11 -c hipe/hipe_x86_glue.S -o obj/i386-pc-solaris2.11/opt/smp/hipe_x86_glue.o
>   Assembler: 
>           "/var/tmp//ccH5a4cn.s", line 1 : Syntax error
>           Near line: " .section ".text""
>   gmake[3]: *** [obj/i386-pc-solaris2.11/opt/smp/hipe_x86_glue.o] Error 1
>   gmake[3]: Leaving directory `/home/admin/Workarea/otp/erts/emulator'

Any ideas? Maybe I need to disable some feature in `./configure` or am I missing a required package? I tried to compile with gcc-45 as provided by Oracle and gcc 4.6.2 from OpenCSW.

Comment: I tried `./configure --enable-m32-build` which results in a different error: `hipe/hipe_process.h:72:12: error: 'ERTS_ALC_T_HIPE' undeclared (first use in this function)`.

Comment: Erlang installation is a pain on all Solaris Version/Platforms. I suggest, You should try the Erlang mailing list for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Made OTP R14B04 compile. First you need to remove some stuff that causes the build to fail (see also: http://www.dev-eth0.de/couchdb-on-opensolaris-part-1-erlang/).

```
vim erts/emulator/drivers/common/inet_drv.c
```

Search for `SIOCGIFHWADDR` and remove everything between `#ifdef SIOCGIFHWADDR` and `#elif defined(SIOCGENADDR)`:

Before (`erts/emulator/drivers/common/inet_drv.c`):

```
...
#ifdef SIOCGIFHWADDR
    if (ioctl(desc->s, SIOCGIFHWADDR, (char *)&ifreq) < 0)
        break;
    buf_check(sptr, s_end, 1+2+IFHWADDRLEN);
    *sptr++ = INET_IFOPT_HWADDR;
    put_int16(IFHWADDRLEN, sptr); sptr += 2;
    /* raw memcpy (fix include autoconf later) */
    sys_memcpy(sptr, (char*)(&ifreq.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data), IFHWADDRLEN);
    sptr += IFHWADDRLEN;
#elif defined(SIOCGENADDR)
...
```

After (`erts/emulator/drivers/common/inet_drv.c`):

```
...
#ifdef SIOCGIFHWADDR
#elif defined(SIOCGENADDR)
...
```

And then run:

```
./configure --enable-m32-build --disable-hipe
gmake
sudo gmake install
```

---

***Caveat:** I'm trying to build couchdb on Solaris 11 and it when running a the first test from the build in test suite (basics.js) from within the browser couchdb crashes. Not sure what is exactly the reason, might be erlang? Will investigate...*